# Why aren't my HTML5 video control buttons working with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am working on a project using `<video>`, trying to make external HTML buttons play/pause, rewind slow, rewind fast, and fast forward control a video using JavaScript. I have the buttons appearing where I want them, but when I try to use them in the browser, they don't do anything to control the video, and the play button doesn't switch to pause and vice versa. I've tried for hours, looking all over the Web to find anything that I can use to help. Most solutions I find are using jQuery which I understand is easier, but it's not what I need. I just want to do it using pure JavaScript so I can better understand it. Included is my existing code. Any help on how I can get them to work would be appreciated!

**HTML:**

```
<script src="sample.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <video id="video" poster="images/art/preview.png" width="100%" controls>
            <source src="images/art/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"">
                <source src="images/art/sample.webm" type="video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"">
                    <source src="images/art/sample.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video

                    </video>
                    <div id="buttonbar">
                        <button type="button" id="fastBck">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" id="rew">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" id="play-pause">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" id="fastFwd">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
window.onload = function() {
    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    var playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause");
    var rewButton = document.getElementById("rew");
    var fastBckButton = document.getElementById("fastBck");
    var fastFwdButton = document.getElementById("fastFwd");
}

playButton.addEventListener("click", function(){

    if (video.paused==true) {
        video.play();
        playButton.className="glyphicon glyphicon-pause";
    } else{
        video.pause();
        playButton.className="glyphicon glyphicon-play";
    }
})

rewButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //not sure exactly how to use currentTime to rewind, or fast forward
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. let the browser pick the right codecs for your video
2. you defined your variables out of scope (you've encapsulated them inside the `onload` function)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var video = document.getElementById("video");
  var playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause");
  var rewButton = document.getElementById("rew");
  var fastBckButton = document.getElementById("fastBck");
  var fastFwdButton = document.getElementById("fastFwd");

  playButton.addEventListener("click", function(){

    if (video.paused===true) {
      video.play();
      playButton.className="glyphicon glyphicon-pause";
    } else{
      video.pause();
      playButton.className="glyphicon glyphicon-play";
    }
  });

  rewButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //not sure exactly how to use currentTime to rewind, or fast forward
  });
};
```

```css
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">

    <video id="video"  width="100%" controls>
      <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video
    </video>
    <div id="buttonbar">
      <button type="button" id="fastBck"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward"></span></button> 
      <button type="button" id="rew"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span></button>
      <button type="button" id="play-pause"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></button>
      <button type="button" id="fastFwd"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward"></span></button>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Good luck with the fast forward and your other methods

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() { 
       var video = document.getElementById("video"); 
        var playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause"); 
    var rewButton = document.getElementById("rew"); 
    var fastBckButton = document.getElementById("fastBck"); 
    var fastFwdButton = document.getElementById("fastFwd");
playButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
 if (video.paused==true) { 
   video.play(); 
   playButton.className="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"; 
    } else{   
        video.pause(); 
        playButton.className="glyphicon glyphicon-play"; 
     } 
   })                 
    rewButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
       //not sure exactly how to use    
       currentTime to rewind, or fast forward 
    })
 }
```

Move listeners inside onload function. Listeners won't be attached until the page is loaded. Respect for wanting to use vanilla JS, however unnecessary.

Comment: It's still not working, I'm not sure what I'm missing here.